# typescript: Infer generic requirement of type

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

## Question

How do you infer the generic requirement (whats in the extends part) of a generic class?

## Explaination

```
// UserGivenClassThatCouldHaveAnyGeneric
class A<T extends string> {
  constructor(a: T) {}
}
```

How would I infer that the generic `T` must extends `string`. I need this information in an conditional statement.

I have tried the following

```
type E<W> = any extends A<infer T> ? W extends T ? A<W> : void : void
```

`E` should be void when given `W` does not extend what is required by `T`, but should be A when it does. However this does not work at all, event though there is no syntax error warning displayed.

Comment: Like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVaBTAHgFxQOwCYwgwCcBLbAcwD5oBvAKGmmAHttCiBXYDZogCjAAuaIgCUtaAF86k6HToYAngAcU0AKLwA6tQC80bCgBuKIqkw58ceGQBmpkdQD80ANpaAuuax4YrxF4uCDrQwkbMJLihBsam8kA) maybe?  Let me know if that works for you and I'll write it up if so; otherwise please specify how it fails to meet your needs.  Good luck.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, thanks alot! Doesnt it work without the tuple as well? Like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVaBTAHgFxQOwCYwgwCcBLbAcwD5oBvAKGmmAHttCiBXYDZogCjAAuaIgCUtaAF86k6HToYAngAcU0AKLwA6tQC80bCgBuKIqkw58ceGQBmpkdQD80Leax4YyFwh3RhRswkuP4GxqbySqqo0Pqa7GRU8kA)?

Comment: It depends; do you want `E<"a" | "b">` to be `A<"a" | "b">` or `A<"a"> | A<"b">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is to change `E<W>` to something like this:

```
type E<W> = never extends A<infer T> ? [W] extends [T] ? A<W> : void : never
```

First, a conditional type where the checked type is `any`, like `any extends X ? Y : Z`, will end up being evaluated as the union `Y | Z` for most types `X`.  That is, `any` is special-cased to take both branches of the conditional type.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#27418](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27418) for some discussion about this.  Assuming you were only trying to use the true branch of the conditional type, it would be better to use `never extends X ? Y : Z`.  Generally, `never extends X` will always be true, and then the result will be `Y`.  Also, if there's ever a type you don't want to worry about cluttering up your unions, you should make it `never`, not `void`.  The type `A | never` evaluates to `A`, whereas `A | void` generally does not.

So let's change `type E<W> = any extends A<infer T> ? W extends T ? A<W> : void : void` to `type E<W> = never extends A<infer T> ? W extends T ? A<W> : void : never`.

---

Now the question that remains is: what do you want to do when `W` is itself a union type?  If you leave `E<W>` defined with `W extends T` instead of `[W] extends [T]`, it will be treated as a [*distributive* conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).  That means if `W` is a union type like `A | B | C`, then `E<W>` will evaluate the conditional for *each* member of that union and unite the results, producing the equivalent of `E<A> | E<B> | E<C>`.  Maybe that's what you want, but probably not.  After all, if `W` is `string | number`, you probably want `void` coming out, not `A<string> | void`, right?

The rule for when conditional types become distributive is that you are checking a "naked" or "bare" generic type parameter.   Since `W` is a generic type parameter, the conditional type `W extends T ? ...` will be distributive.  The easiest way to turn off this behavior is to "clothe" the type parameter with something covariant, like a single-element tuple type.  So it becomes `[W] extends [T] ? ...`.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVaBTAHgFxQOwCYwgwCcBLbAcwD5oBvAKGmmAHttCiBXYDZogCjAAuaIgCUtaAF86k6HToYAngAcU0AKLwA6tQC80bCgBuKIqkw58ceGQBmpkdQD80ANpaAuuax4YrxF4uCDrQwkbMJLihBsam8kqq0ABq0Pqa7GTk0AA+BhwAtgBGppQA3NAA9BXQ4ZEKKmpaqRrwAERgrTnQrYWtZZXVCO2duT190EA)